# Identifying distro on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, software-distribution

I followed instructions to get distro on my Raspberry Pi and got the following:

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release`
`PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"`
`NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"`
`VERSION_ID="10"`
`VERSION="10 (buster)"`
`VERSION_CODENAME=buster`
`ID=raspbian`
`ID_LIKE=debian`

How do I extract the distribution from this? Next time someone asks how do I answer?

Comment: How would you like to extract it ? With shell commands ? A script ?

Answer (score 0):

The content of that file is full of variable so:

```
source  /etc/os-release && echo $PRETTY_NAME
```

Replace the variable name with the one you are interested of.

You can also use the `lsb_release -a` command to detect the distribution